# How to approach an unusual quadratic question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Question**: $a,b\in\mathbb{R}\mid a\neq 0$ When the polynomial $x^2-2ax+a^4$ is divided by $x+b$ the remainder is $1$. The polynomial $bx^2+x+1 $ has $ax-1$ as a factor. What is the value of $b$

**My Attempt**
$$\frac{x^2-2ax+a^4}{x+b}=... \frac{1}{x+b}\Rightarrow b^2+2ab+a^4=1$$
$$bx^2+x+1=(ax-1)(b/a-1)\Rightarrow a^2+a+b=0$$
How do you proceed from here? Am I approaching this problem correctly?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain how you made the implications but I agree with the conclusions. I am getting two possible values of $b,$ however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for $x=\frac{1}{a}$

$$\frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{2a}{a}+a^4=0$$

$$\frac{1}{a^2}-2+a^4=0$$

$$(\frac{1}{a}-a)^2+a^2=0$$

$$a\not=0, a=-1, a=1$$

Let $a=-1$ then $x^2+2x+1=0$

for $x=-b$

$$b^2-2b+1=1$$

$$b^2-2b=0$$

Let $a=1$ then $x^2-2x+1=0$

for $x=-b$

$$b^2+2b+1=1$$

$$b^2+2b=0$$

Answer (score 0):

From your equations we have $(a+b)^2 = (a^2)^2= a^4$.

Hence $1 = b^2 + 2ab + a^4 = (b+a)^2-a^2 + a^4 = 2a^4 - a^2$.

This is a quadratic equation in $a^2$, which can be solved to obtains value(s) of $a$ and $b$.